# How to use ternary operator for the jsx?

Tags: reactjs

Hi i want to use the ternary operator for rendering the jsx.

What i am trying to do?
I have to render two components namely ParentComponent and ChildComponent based on some conditions being true.

ParentComponent should be rendered when variable_1 and variable_2 is true. and ChildComponent should be rendered when variable_1 is true and variable_2 is false.

I have tried below,

```
render = () => {
    return (
        {variable_2
            ? <ParentComponent/>
            : <ChildComponent/>
        }
    )
}
```

in the above code, i have included only the variable_2. how do i also check for variable_1 using ternary operator.

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: There is nothing special about the conditional operator and JSX. You use it the same way you'd use it for any other kind of value: `return variable_2 && variable_1 ? <ParentComponent/> : (variable_1 ? <ChildComponent/> : null);` The outer `{` denote the start of an object literal which is wrong. Just writing two `if` statements might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function and put the logic in there. Ternaries can be hard to read, especially if you start to nest them. Better to be explicit in your intentions so when you come back to it in a month or so you can still see what it's doing.

```
const renderContent = () => {
  if (var1 && var2) return <ParentComponent/>
  if (var1 && !var2) return <ChildComponent/>
  return null
}

return renderContent()
```

Answer (score 1):

**The requirement can be simplified as:**

> ***When variable_1 is true***
>
> - If variable_2 is also true, then show 'parent'
> - If variable_2 is false, then show 'child'

---

> ***When variable_1 is false***,
>
> Show blank space, regardless of the value of variable_2

**Implementation using tenary operator:**

```
return(
    variable_1
        ? (variable_2 ? <ParentComponent /> : <ChildComponent />)
        : null
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is more a ternary operator question than a react question.
Let's say A is parent component and B is child component

```
const output = variable_1 && variable_2 ? A
                   : variable_1 && !variable_2 ?
                         B : null;
```

I'm calling null because you didn't provide the other cases, like when var1 is false and var2 is true, or when both are false

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the code by this given below :

`render = () => {
    return (
        {
          variable_1 && variable_2
            ? <ParentComponent />
            : variable_1
            ? <ChildComponent />
            : null
        }
    )
}`